# How do I make a UIImageView not be wider than the view it's contained in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I set the image of a UIImageView to an image that is 1024x1024, and as a result a lot of the image is not visible, especially width wise, and cut off the edges of the screen.

I tried using `clipsToBounds`:

```
UIImageView *imageFromLink = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:responseObject];
imageFromLink.clipsToBounds = YES;
[darkOverlayView addSubview:imageFromLink];
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything, and the image is still too big for the view.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to change the `contentMode` property for the desired effect. `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` is most likely what you'll want.

Comment: Also the frame needs to be set.

Comment: `AspectFill` is probably not what you want. That will most likely distort the image. `AspectFit` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have the set the image view's frame to the size you want. By default it will be the size of the image.

```
UIImageView *imageFromLink = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:responseObject];
imageFromLink.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageFromLink.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
[darkOverlayView addSubview:imageFromLink];
```

Also set the `contentMode` so the image is scaled properly in the smaller image view.

Comment: So there's no way to automatically calculate what the desiredWidth and height should be?

Comment: Not really. It's up to you to know what that is. Most likely the width should be `darkOverlayView.bounds.size.width` but maybe not. It all depends on your needs for the image view.

Comment: But what if I just want to say don't be outside the main screen's bounds? There's *nothing* to calculate that for me?

Comment: I just told you how. Use the width of the parent view or perhaps the width of the view controller's view.

Comment: Yes, but how does that then calculate the other dimension properly? Or rather, what do I put for the other one?

Comment: Again, it depends on your needs. If you just want to fill the screen, set the image view's size to the view controller's view's size. If there are other views, you need to pick a height that allows for the other views.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the imageview's frame equal to the container's bounds.

```
UIImageView *imageFromLink = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:responseObject];
imageFromLink.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageFromLink.frame = darkOverlayView.bounds;
[darkOverlayView addSubview:imageFromLink];
```